# Redirecting AWS cli output to awk in order to keep timestamp logs of operations

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awk

I'm attempting to redirect the output from an AWS cli command (retrieving files from an S3 bucket) into awk which will prefix the output with a timestamp and then write it out to a file - to effectively provide a logging mechanism.

General stdout output looks like this:

```
download: s3://mbd-wombats/IMG_0210.jpg to aws/IMG_0210.jpg         5 file(s) remaining
download: s3://mbd-wombats/IMG_0209.jpg to aws/IMG_0209.jpg     4 file(s) remaining
download: s3://mbd-wombats/IMG_0207.jpg to aws/IMG_0207.jpg      3 file(s) remaining
download: s3://mbd-wombats/IMG_0208.jpg to aws/IMG_0208.jpg      2 file(s) remaining
download: s3://mbd-wombats/IMG_0206.jpg to aws/IMG_0206.jpg       1 file(s) remaining
```

The command I'm attempting to use is this:

`aws s3 cp --recursive s3://mbd-wombats /home/martyn/aws >> >(awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S ") $0}' > /home/martyn/wibble.txt)`

Unfortunately, it just writes out to the file the same as stdout.  Whereas the following:

`echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' &>> >(awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S ") $0}' > test.log)`

works:

`2018-04-04:14:23:12 one
2018-04-04:14:23:12 two
2018-04-04:14:23:12 three`

My question is - why isn't the output from aws being parsed through correctly?

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turns out that aws' CLI spits out returns rather than newlines, so it was a case of throwing in tr "\r" "\n" to fix that before throwing everything into awk, e.g.

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://mbd-wombats /home/martyn/aws | tr "\r" "\n" > >(awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S ") $0}' >> /home/martyn/s3-sync.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the progress is reported in stdout or stderr.  However, with `bash-4` you can pipe both stdout and stderr easily

```
$ aws ...  |& awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S"), $0}' > log
```